# Inheritance of generic typed method from abstract class -- convert to specific type

Tags: java, generics, overriding, abstract-class, type-bounds

(Working in Java)
I have an abstract class with generic typing throughout the whole class:

```
public abstract class ConnectionProcessor<T>
{
    public void process()
    {
        for (List<T> resultsPage : connection)
        {
            processPage(resultsPage);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void processPage(List<T> resultsPage);
}
```

I have another class that extends said abstract class, with the following declaration:

```
public class AlbumProcessor<Album> extends ConnectionProcessor
{
    @Override
    protected void processPage(List resultsPage)
    {
        //Do stuff here specific to Album
    }
}
```

This declaration works fine, but in `processPage` I want to do `Album`-specific things, and I try to avoid casting when I don't need to use it.  I would PREFER this to be the method declaration:

```
protected void processPage(List<Album> resultsPage)
```

But this doesn't meet the requirements for overriding `processPage` from `ConnectionProcessor`.  Why is this?  How can I get the desired behavior?  I would think that in `AlbumProcessor` I could just plug in `<Album>` everywhere `ConnectionProcessor` has `<T>`, but that just isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
//extend prameterized version of ConnectionProcessor<T> with Album as actual type argument
public class AlbumProcessor extends ConnectionProcessor<Album> {
```

instead of

```
public class AlbumProcessor<Album> extends ConnectionProcessor {
```

When you do the above you are exteding the raw version of the generic type `ConnectionProcessor<T>` and introducing a new formal type parameter - `Album` (like `T`) which is not an actual type argument in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I think you answered my "why is this" part of the question the best

Answer (score 2):

That's because you didn't bind your super class Generic type `T` to `Album`.

Rather, this is what you should do:

```
public class AlbumProcessor extends ConnectionProcessor<Album>
```

So, when you'll override your method `processPage`, (using an IDE), it will generate code as follows:

```
@Override
protected void processPage(List<Album> resultsPage)
{
    //Do stuff here specific to Album
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AlbumProcessor extends ConnectionProcessor<Album>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: -

```
public class AlbumProcessor extends ConnectionProcessor<Album>
{
    @Override
    protected void processPage(List<Album> resultsPage)
    {
        //Do stuff here specific to Album
    }
}
```

You need to bind your super class with the type you want to give as a type parameter to your List in your method declaration..

Answer (score 1):

How bout something more like this.

```
import java.util.List;

public abstract class ConnectionProcessor<T>
{
    public void process()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    protected abstract void processPage(List<? extends T> resultsPage);
}
```

...

```
public class ProcessorImpl extends ConnectionProcessor<Album> {

    protected void processPage(List<? extends Album> resultsPage) {
        for(Album result : resultsPage){
            System.out.println(result.getAlbumName());
        }
    }

}
```

...

```
public class Album {
    public String getAlbumName(){
        return "Sweet Smooth SOunds of the 70's";
    }
}
```